# Factory Girl ArgumentError: Factory not registered:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I have gone through what seems like all the correct steps and I continue to get this error.
From the gemfile:

```
 group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', require: false
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.0', require: false
  gem 'faker'
 end
```

spec_helper.rb:

```
require 'factory_girl_rails'
RSpec.configure do |config|
 config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
 FactoryGirl.definition_file_paths = [File.expand_path('../factories', __FILE__)]
 FactoryGirl.find_definitions
 FactoryGirl.factories.clear
end
```

spec/factories/company.rb:
    require 'spec_helper'
    require 'faker'

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :company do
    name { Faker::Name.name }
    system_name { Faker::Company.name }
    domain { Faker::Internet.url }
  end
end
```

company_spec.rb:
    require 'spec_helper'

```
describe 'Company' do
  it 'has a valid factory' do
    FactoryGirl.build(:company).should be_valid
  end
end
```

Getting the error Failure/Error:

```
Failure/Error: FactoryGirl.create(:company).should be_valid
     ArgumentError:
       Factory not registered: company
```

Comment: Why are you calling `FactoryGirl.factories.clear` in spec_helper? That looks like it means you'll never have any factories.

Comment: @Dave I get a different error when I take that out     NameError:
       uninitialized constant Company

Comment: Have you defined a `Company` class? FactoryGirl tries to instantiate a class matching your declaration of `factory :company`.

Comment: I do have a Company class. The error 'NameError: uninitialized constant Company' seems as though it can't find it. Idk why that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had everything but much of it in the wrong place:

gemfile needed to be:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', require: false
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.0', require: false
  gem 'faker'
 end
```

everything in the spec_helper I moved to rails_helper.rb and got rid of two lines:

```
require 'factory_girl_rails'
RSpec.configure do |config|
 config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
 FactoryGirl.definition_file_paths = [File.expand_path('../factories', __FILE__)]
 // FactoryGirl.find_definitions // got rid of this
 // FactoryGirl.factories.clear // got rid of this
end
```

company_spec.rb:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe 'Company' do
 it 'has a valid factory' do
  expect(build(:company)).to be_valid
 end
end
```

Most of this info was from the comments and derived from this [tutorial](http://www.webascender.com/Blog/ID/566/Testing-Rails-4-Apps-With-RSpec-3-Part-I#.VcIve5NVhBe) about rspec and factory girl.